# Don't know how to post with redux form, can't map state to PostNew

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm currently building a fairly simple MERN stack application, and can't seem to get redux form to work. 
here I have my PostNew.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostForm from './PostForm';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

class PostNew extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { show: false };
    this.toggleForm = this.toggleForm.bind(this);
  }

  toggleForm() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
    this.state.show
      ? (document.querySelector('.newButton').innerHTML = 'new post')
      : (document.querySelector('.newButton').innerHTML = 'cancel');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="newButton" onClick={this.toggleForm}>
          new post
        </button>
        {this.state.show ? (
          <PostForm
            onPostSubmit={() => {
              this.props.submitPost(formValues);
            }}
          />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  // return {
  //   formValues: state.form.postForm.values
  // }
  console.log(state)
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(PostNew);
```

and it's PostForm child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import formFields from './formFields';
import _ from 'lodash';

class PostForm extends Component {
  renderFields() {
    return _.map(formFields, ({ label, name }) => {
      return (
        <form key={name} onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.onPostSubmit)} autoComplete="off">
          <Field
            key={name}
            type="text"
            component="input"
            label={label}
            name={name}
          />
        </form>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderFields()}</div>;
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'postForm'
})(PostForm);
```

As you can see in my Post form, I submit the form and it updates the state, as I can console log the state in postNew. However, only when I type something in my search input does the state update, therefore state.form.postForm.values is null.
Once I have this.props.formValues, I want to then pass it to my action creator that I've written, which takes the values as an argument.

I'd be incredibly grateful if someone could push me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are creating a new (different) form for every field. You should have you form tag inside the render method, and just return Field for every form field.

Comment: Thank you so much, how could I not see that? I'm going to try and fix it now. Cheers!